# How to refresh dynamic listview?

Tags: android

I have a dynamic listview and I want to refresh the list when any new item is added.
How can I do this.Pls help me.

Thanks,
Monali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `setListAdapter(yourAdapter);`

Make your adapter to ListAdapter find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)

then just use

`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and you are done !

Answer (score 2):

Call  [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your adapter

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo for how u can do that http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

1) create a method

2) set adapterView in that method.

3) at click event of any image button call that method.

or to put Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I think this would be easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this like...
I have custom row for list. It has textview and I can change it's value ...

```
((TextView)(myWatchList.getChildAt(INDEX - myWatchList.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.symbolCountTV))).setText(NEWSTRING);
```